# Square trailing mouse in Ubuntu 20.04?

Tags: 20.04, mouse

There is square trailing mouse effect when I move my mouse around anything with white background.

This screenshot is captured at https://askubuntu.com/. Normal page doesn't have the square trailing effect.

Apparently this appear when I have `Universal Access > Zoom` enabled in Ubuntu 20.04 and gone when I disable it.

How do I troubleshoot and fix this kind of problem?

[image]

Normal (`Universal Access > Zoom` disabled)

[image]